# How to access a drive by volume label in a python script in Ubuntu

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am writing a python script that copies some data to an external drive attached to Ubuntu host. I do not want to pass the device file of the drive to the python script. But I can set the Volume label of the drive and export it as an environment variable in the linux shell.

My question is how to I access this shell environment variable in my python script ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `os` module provides access to environmental variables. Suppose that you have exported `$VOL="/BLAH"`. Then, in Python:

```
import os
my_path = os.environ['VOL']
```